# Ansible string concatenation into config file

Tags: ansible

I have a list of variables `("/dev/sda", "/dev/sdb")` which I would like to to dynamically update a config file.

The config file is finally expected to look like

```
filter = [ "a|/dev/sda[145]|", "a|/dev/sdb[145]|", "a|/dev/mapper/3500.*part1|", "r|.*|" ]
```

Currently, the config file looks like this.

```
filter = [ "a|/dev/mapper/3500.*part1|", "r|.*|" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to my own question. I am not sure if this is the "jinja" way of doing things.

```
{% set ldsk = [] %}
{% for disk in ldisks  %}
        {{ ldsk.append( "\"|a"+ disk +"[145]|\"") }}
{% endfor %}
filter = [ {{ ldsk | join(", ") }}, "a|/dev/mapper/3500.*part1|", "r|.*|" ]
```